# Is there a way to look at the previous evaluation within a CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created the following table in Excel as an example. I would like to do a similar expression (like the formula shown in Excel) in SQL Server on a similar looking table. The columns *row_num* and *switch* were already created based on previous `CASE` statements.

[Click for Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPHbr.png)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for having a look!

PS: in case image does not work:

```
EXCEL     |   A    |    B   |   C   | 
1         |row_num | switch | group |
2         | 1      | 0      | 1     |
3         | 2      | 1      | 1     |
4         | 3      | 1      | 1     |
5         | 4      | 0      | 2     |
6         | 5      | 0      | 3     |
7         | 6      | 1      | 3     |
8         | 7      | 1      | 3     |
9         | 8      | 0      | 4     |
10        | 1      | 0      | 5     |
11        | 2      | 1      | 5     |
12        | 3      | 0      | 6     |
13        | 4      | 1      | 6     |

Formula on cell C3: IF(B3=1;C2;C2+1) (etc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum of the cases when `switch = 0`.

However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So you need a column (or multiple columns) that specify the ordering.  In your example, you can use the excel row number, but your data might have a more appropriate column.

Hence:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when switch = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by excel_row) as grouping
from t;
```

If `switch` only takes on two values, you can simplify this to:

```
select t.*,
       sum(1 - switch) over (order by excel_row) as grouping
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: @renojack . . . Is there a reason you didn't accept this answer, which was the first answer?

Comment: Pardon me, I misread. Thought the other one was first!

Answer (score 0):

I think a window sum does what you want:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(case when switch = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by excel_row) grp
from mytable t
```

If you always have `0`/`1` values in column `switch`, then this can be simplified:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(1 - switch) over(order by excel_row) grp
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @GMB This is what I was looking for!